# How do I retrieve Month and Year from SQL query>

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have the below snippet which returns month from my created_at timestamp. I am wanting this to return as MM-YYYY but not sure of the syntax. This is in a laravel implementation. I have tried to add 'MONTH, YEAR' but no luck.

```
$data = [
        'data' => Payment::selectSub('MONTH(created_at)', 'month')
        ->selectSub('SUM(payment_amount)', 'total_payments')
        ->groupBy('month')
        ->get()];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use SQL's `date_format` function.

```
selectSub('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%m-%Y")', 'month')
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format for a full list of different formatting options.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that but I must have had a typo. Your answer works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$data = [
    'data' => Payment::selectSub('MONTH(created_at)', 'year(created_at)')
    ->selectSub('SUM(payment_amount)', 'total_payments')
```